# Flask / SQLAlchemy - Database Connection Leak - How to debug?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-socketio

I have a Flask Application and I am using SQLAlchemy as an ORM. Unfortunately, Im running into the problem that I get the error: "psql: FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections".

I have increased the max_connections to 25 but the problem remains. I check the pg_stat_activity and I am seeing that the connections are idling so I kill them which temporarily solves the problem until I hit the wall again.

My question is - How can I start debugging this? I am a bit lost where to look for hints.

Comment: Probably sessions are not being closed correctly.  But it's impossible to tell without a [mre].

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thank you for your reply. I would love to add example, unfortunately I wouldn't know what part of my code to post (the project is already quite big), the issue happens at random and I wouldn't know what queries are leaving the DB connection occupied.

Do you happen to know how I could approach this to find at least more information to post for you guys?

Comment: where did you set `max_connections` on postgres?

Comment: @TalhaJunaid, yes - on the managed Postgres Database under pool connection I have maxed out what is possible.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to restrict the number of connections.
in flask_sqlalchemy you can specify that using `SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS` in engine options.

```
SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS = {
        # The number of long-running connections to the database to keep open
        'pool_size':  10,
        # This setting causes the pool to recycle connections after the given number of seconds
        # has passed. It defaults to -1, or no timeout.
        'pool_recycle': 10 * 60)
}
```